# C++ override a member variable (std::vector)

Tags: c++, casting, overriding, covariant

here are the classes which my question is about

```
class Graph {}
class SceneGraph : public Graph {}

class Node {
public:
    virtual Node* getNode(int index) { return mNodeList[index]; }

protected:
    vector<Node*> mNodeList;
    Graph* mGraph;
}

class TransformationNode : public Node {
public:
    TransformationNode* getNode(int index) { return static_cast<TransformationNode*> (mNodelist[index]); }

    void _update() {
        auto beg = mNodeList.begin();
        auto end = mNodeList.end();
        while (begin != end) {
            TransformationNode* node = static_cast<TransformationNode*> (*beg);
            node->_update();
        }
    }

private:
    bool mUpdated;
    SceneGraph* mGraph;    
}
```

First of all, I want to talk about the problems I solved. They may helps others. And you can confirm me if I am right ^^

1. Can I override a function with a different return type ?
   Node* getNode(int index) became TransformationNode* getNode(int index)

   > > Yes as long as return types are covariant : http://www.tolchz.net/?p=33
2. Can I override a member ?

   > > I don't know about overriding but a variable with the same name in the derived class will hide the one in the base class

And there is the problem I really want to get around some how

In the TransformationNode class I did many (IMHO) avoidable type casting from base class to derived one. I definitely know that all the elements in the mNodeList vector are TransformationNodes but to process mNodeList I have to type cast them. 
The inheritance is correct I mean TransformationNode is a Node 
mNodeList holds child nodes of the node and it can not have a copy in the derived class which holds typecasted version of Nodes
And finaly I can even use reinterpered_cast if static_cast is more costly. Can you inform  me about cost of these operations ? are they really big performance issues ? 

assert (dynamic_cast)... kind of precaution has already been taken.

**briefly I want my compiler to know that mGraph is actually a SceneGraph* and mNodeList holds TransformationNode* this helps me to avoid lost of type casting.**

*Thank you for taking your time*

Comment: I would just move the variable `mNodeList` from the base class into the derived classes. That gives you the same functionality with no casting

Comment: It's strange that a `Node` contains a list of more... nodes. I think redesign would solve most problems here.

Comment: @KerrekSB I guess those are child nodes or something

Comment: @SethCarnegie: But that's what's broken: If they're child nodes and each child can be an *arbitrary* node, then you cannot just static-cast them to one particular node. Either the cast is wrong, or the tree is a lie...

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, I didnt think of that when I posted my first comment so its invalid now

Answer (score 1):

1) is correct, you can indeed override (virtual!) base functions if the return type is more derived.

Ad 2): indeed, you cannot "override" members. Redesign the base class if you need more flexible overridable behaviour.

`static_cast` is a *static* operation that is resolved at compile time, so much like `reinterpret_cast` it doesn't have any "cost".

---

As @Seth suggests in the comment, it might be an option to move the container. Ask yourself, can there ever be an abstract `Node`, or is every node actually of some derived concrete type? Perhaps you could make `Node` abstract:

```
struct Node { Node * getNode(size_t index) const = 0; };

struct TransformNode : Node
{
    TransformNode * getNode(size_t index) const { return m_nodes[index]; }
private:
    std::vector<TransformNode *> m_nodes;
};
```

Put the entire *interface* into the base class, but only implement it in each concrete class.